# How to make `_logger.isDebugEnabled()` condition false in Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

How to make `_logger.isDebugEnabled()` condition false in Junit ?

```
private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(InstanceReleaseMachine.class);

if (_logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            _logger.debug("Error from Releasing Instance: " + failure);
        }
```

i tried to my knowledge i can't do it , Please let me know if anyone have done this .

Comment: The usual way is not to instantiate the dependency in the same class using it but inject it.

The surrender to this very common but yet bad design is to use PowerMock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set level = OFF programmatically in unit test:

```
    Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But because that's shared static state, you may break another test by doing that. Tests should never rely on shared static state (nor should applications, if it can be avoided)